# How to add transparent control above video control like wpf label over mediaelement

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, video

I want to add a transparent label or textbox over video control when playing it flickers but in wpf i used label above mediaelement and it was perfect.

How can get the same behavior in c# winforms **or** native c++ or whatever you know?? i'm using vlc media player control

how the wpf do it? the way?

Comment: If this is a winforms/C++ question, why is it tagged c# and wpf?

Comment: just give me the way i'm asking for any available solution the native language must be able to do it as i think

Comment: "Just give me the code" rarely works on StackOverflow.  I still don't know what you're asking or what type of environment.  You said it works in WPF, so go ahead and do it in WPF.

Comment: aha i said the way the method not a list of code lines. i just meant by that you can say something useful that's all

Comment: and if you don't know the way let someone else do. it's already working in wpf but it's required to be done in winforms and i mentioned the c++ because someone else can do what i ask him to do in c++ he don't know the way. the method the solution ha. take it easy \Robaticus/

Comment: Did you find a solution? This is still relevant to me.

Comment: Yes using the vlc lib you can merge images, sounds..., this is awesome look at this c# encapsulation it will help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either:

A. Disable the hardware acceleration for video playback.

B. Use a library for directX and intercept the frames redrawing your content on top of the frame.

This library may help but it's been a couple of years since I played with video technology.

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: you must haven't seen this sentence "i'm using vlc media"

Comment: Did you try option 'A' because I think VLC does use directX depending on the codecs.

Comment: No I didn't i tried to use the marquee functions but the text location was forced by video boundaries, Now I'm trying to move the application to wpf, hopping it will give a perfect success because i used it with windows media player and it worked fine also i read that wpf is highly depending on directx ...